# Complexity and pseudocode explanation

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

We have the following pseudocode

```
Input: An array A storing n ≥ 1 integers.
Output: The sum of the elements in A.
s←A[0]
for i←1 to n−1 do
s←s+A[i]
return s
```

First of all,I have noticed this all the time in pseudocodes like this,why do we write `for i←1 to n−1 do` and not for example for `i←1 to n do` or `for i←1 to n+1 do` ?

Second the complexity of this is O(n-1) so O(n)..I understand why it is O(n),thats what I thought when I saw the code ,but why O(n-1) at first ?

Edit: What Im trying to understand is how did we get O(n-1)

Comment: worrying about psudocode syntax isn't a good use of your time ... O(n±constant) = O(n)... because as n gets large the constant becomes less significant... which you might get based on your question, but it is O(n) because you do something for each element once...

Comment: because i starts at 1 and goest to n-1.... rather than starting at 0 and going to n-1, or starting at 1 and going to n

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of the algorithm is O(N). For a computer O(N+1) , O(N), O(N-1) , O(N-2) is pretty much the same (especially when N is big). So everyone approximates that to O(N). 
He goes with i to N-1 value because the array is starting index is 0. So you have:

A[0] , A[1] ...., A[N-1] ---> N elements in the array.